# Как подключить sass/scss к create-react-app с помощью webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Делаю по [этому](https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760) мануалу. Мануал написан для старой версии CRA, но в комментариях есть правки для текущей версии.

Получилось так:

```
{
  exclude: [
    /\.html$/,
    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    /\.css$/,
    /\.json$/,
    /\.bmp$/,
    /\.gif$/,
    /\.jpe?g$/,
    /\.png$/,
    /\.scss$/,
  ],
  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
  options: {
    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
  },
},
{
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  include: paths.appSrc,
  use: [
    { loader: require.resolve('style-loader') },
    { loader: require.resolve('css-loader') },
    { loader: require.resolve('sass-loader') }
  ]
},
```

Билдится без ошибок, но стили не применяются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой CRA